# How to only foreign key in Prisma not the whole object

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, nestjs, prisma

I've just started learning nestjs and I'm using Prisma as my ORM, I've created two models (Employees, Clients), these models will contain foreign keys , the client will have the employee id and vice versa (a one-to-one relation), but as you will see in the models the employee will contain the whole Client "object", but what I want also is his client's id as an independent column :

this is the models:

```
model Employe {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updated   DateTime @updatedAt

  email String @unique
  hash  String

  nom    String
  prenom String

 // I want the client ID here too
  
  client Client? 

  @@map("employes")
}

model Client {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updated   DateTime @updatedAt

  email String @unique
  hash  String

  nom    String
  prenom String

  EmpId Int?     @unique
  emp   Employe? @relation(fields: [EmpId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)

  @@map("clients")
}
```

So is there any way ?

- Framework: NestJS
- ORM: Prisma
- DB : Postgresql
- Platform: Docker

Comment: What you want to do is add an additional ClientID value to the Client inside the Employe model?

Answer (score 1):

The fields `emp` in the Client model and `client` in Employe model are relation fields so they won't exist in the database, they are just at the prisma level.

You only need to define the foreign key on one side of the relation - [One to One relation Prisma reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/one-to-one-relations#choosing-which-side-should-store-the-foreign-key-in-a-1-1-relation)

You could store clientId on the Employe model as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this link there is an example that can help you:

https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/general-guides/database-workflows/foreign-keys/postgresql

Comment: it says here that I need to write some code and files  by myself, but I've been doing the process using prisma, wouldn't it cause a problem if try to add another file and not using the models. ?

Answer (score 0):

I more or less understand what you mean. I don't understand why you don't set relation, but you can use this structure when creating a client or employe.

to create the employe

```js
await prisma.employe.create({
  data: {
    email: 'blabla',
    hash: 'balbla',
    nom: 'blabla',
    prenom: 'balbla',
    clientId: 123,
    include: {
        client: {
           ...,
        }
    }
  },
})
```

to create the client

```js
await prisma.client.create({
  data: {
    email: 'blabla',
    hash: 'balbla',
    nom: 'blabla',
    prenom: 'balbla',
    employeId: 123,
    include: {
        employe: {
           ...,
        }
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm trying to build a REST API and when I want to return  the employee, it returns either the whole object or just the fields I want as an "object" , and this is not what I'm looking for because I only need  the client's id, I think that your approach is very good, but how can it add the  "employeId: 123" &  "clientId: 123" automatically ?